# Comparing two Arrays using NSPredicate and returns the repeated character

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nspredicate

```
NSArray *MainArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A", @"U", @"U", @"U", nil]; // Array already stored 

NSArray *SubArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A", @"U", nil]; // Array I passed during runtime
```

using these two array, I need to get the `U U` from MainArray.

The concept is that I have to delete the `A U` from MainArray, which I passed during runtime.

```
SampleOutput :
U U
```

Comment: What's special about the 'last 2' `U`s? If you find a match for the whole `SubArray` then exactly those items should be deleted?

Comment: @Wain I need to remove the exact one match from the main array

Comment: And why do you want to use a predicate?

Comment: The objects aren't the same. Each object in the arrays are unique, since you're creating them, so you can't really compare them. In the example above you have to compare two strings to see if they're the same with `isEqualToString`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this approach:

```
NSMutableArray *mainMutableArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:MainArray];
for (id instance in SubArray) {
    NSUInteger position = [mainMutableArray indexOfObject:instance];
    if (position != NSNotFound) {
        [mainMutableArray removeObjectAtIndex:position];
    } 
}
MainArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:mainMutableArray];
```

Comment: How to do this using Predicate?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSSet *set1 = [NSSet setWithArray:MainArray];
NSMutableSet *set2 = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:SubArray];
[set2 minusSet:set1];
```

try this code..

Comment: this does not produce the desired result of the repeated U U remaining in the set/array

Comment: You can also use this
NSMutableArray *arrayOneCopy = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:MainArray];
[arrayOneCopy removeObjectsInArray:SubArray];

Comment: Guys i need to remove the exact one match from the MainArray. And note that i should predicate to do this,.. Is there any possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15743326/comparing-two-arrays-with-nspredicate
See this link which is compare two array with predicates.